# Blender game engine track to a property

Tags: python, game-engine, objects, logic-bricks

I there any way to duplicate the action of the `Edit object > Track to` Actuator; so that it can track to a game property and not a object? It would be used to track multiple objects without having to list them all as separate track to actuators in the logic bricks.

[blend file demo](http://www.pasteall.org/blend/28630)

Comment: I really hope this question to get answered, I don't want to list all the AI separately :S.

Comment: The link to your demo is dead.

Comment: Almost 5 years later, and the link is still dead.  #sad mess

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can only track one object at any given time, so you'll need to define a set of priorities by which a single target can be selected from a group of valid candidates (objects with the relevant property).

For example, if you wanted to track the closest object with the relevant property, you could do it with this function:

```
# track.py

def target_prop(cont):
    self = cont.owner
    objects = self.scene.objects

    tracked = [o for o in objects if self["target_prop"] in o]
    tracked.sort(key=lambda o: self.getDistanceTo(o))

    target, *_ = tracked

    act_track, *_ = cont.actuators
    act_track.object = target

    for act in cont.actuators:
        cont.activate(act)
```

Example: [track_to_prop.blend](https://www.dropbox.com/s/r7pmpc4v5tnjl9q/track_to_prop.blend?dl=1)

As you can see, you can specify the target property via a property on the tracking object (target_prop in this case). Also, you can set the always sensor to "true level triggering" (aka: "pulse mode"), to constantly re-evaluate the closest target, if that's required.

Comment: Will you add some info as to what `*_` on lines 8 and 10 does? Also will to explain why you need to loop through the actuators to activate them. Thanks

Comment: @David That's just [iterable unpacking](http://legacy.python.org/dev/peps/pep-3132/) syntax, to get the first element. The variable preceded by the star (the underscore in this case) is a list containing the rest of the elements, with `act_track` referencing the first. As for the actuators: You don't _need_ to use a loop, as long as you can activate the relevant actuators, but I think a loop makes sense in this case, because I want to activate all that are connected, and that's what `cont.actuators` represents.